# iBooks is broken in root account

Tags: high-sierra, books, root

Due to permission issues, I'm using root account on macOS High Sierra. However, a number of things don't work, and one example of such is that iBooks is broken. Upon launch, the following dialog is displaced:
[image]
"Reset Library" and "Try Again" causes the same dialog to appear again.
Attempting to launch it from the command line gives the following output:

```
objc[30122]: Class bb74bdd798ceadff5c1f0c2b is implemented in both /Applications/iBooks.app/Contents/Frameworks/BKPlatformCore.framework/Versions/A/BKPlatformCore (0x10f54f150) and /Applications/iBooks.app/Contents/MacOS/iBooks (0x10e770a30). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
2020-06-25 10:14:40.898 iBooks[30122:981215] TISFileInterrogator updateSystemInputSources false but old data invalid: currentCacheHeaderPtr nonNULL? 0, ->cacheFormatVersion 0, ->magicCookie 00000000, inputSourceTableCountSys 0
Keyboard Layouts: duplicate keyboard layout identifier -14934.
Keyboard Layouts: keyboard layout identifier -14934 has been replaced with -28673.
2020-06-25 10:14:41.079 iBooks[30122:981260] Unsupported configuration. Please update your BookKit.framework.
```

The reason I wanted to use iBooks is because I read digital books and Preview does not always remember where I am, especially if it crashes for some reason. I also heard that it is designed quite well.

Comment: Books have been stored in ~/Library/Containers under something like iBooks or BooksX. Not sure which it is for HS. Try getting info and making sure you have R&W permissions as well as make sure you are the owner (and apply to all sub-items)

Comment: If you have permission issues I would suggest your os is broken and I am not surprised rhat things don't work. Fix the underlying problem first.

Comment: Your wording  says you have a problem. Programs are not designed to run as root eg the /Library path is used for other things. Your admin account should allow full normal use. If it does not then ask how to fix a particular issue

Comment: Lso root does not have full write access. See how catalina partions the system disk to have a read only volume also look at system integrity protection